# Lyx change language with find replace

Tags: regex, pdf, latex, lyx

I have written a lot of text in greek with selected language "greek" in lyx 2.1 . The problem is that there are words and characters in english in there and when i output to pdf with pdflatex they are transformed into the matching greek characters. I suppose i need to change the language of every english word in there to english, but that sounds very repetitive... I am wondering if i can use regex to match english characters and change their language with find replace somehow. I have successfuly managed to match english characters with this capture group `\regexp{([\backslash x00-\backslash x7F]+)\endregexp{}}` but i dont know what to replace it with. Any ideas?

PS: does lyx regex even have backreferences or are capture groups just there for no reason?